# Cannot call member function std::string Sportist::getIme() without object

Tags: c++, class, member-functions

I have a class A:

```
class Sportist{
    private:
        string ime;
        int godina_na_ragjanje;
        int godisna_zarabotuvacka_EUR;
    public:
        Sportist(string i, int g_n_r, int g_z_EUR){
            ime = i;
            godina_na_ragjanje = g_n_r;
            godisna_zarabotuvacka_EUR = g_z_EUR;
        }
        string getIme(){
            return ime;
        }
        int getGodinaNaRagjanje(){
            return godina_na_ragjanje;
        }
        int getGodisnaZarabotuvackaEUR(){
            return godisna_zarabotuvacka_EUR;
        }
};
```

And class B using the class A as public:

```
class Fudbaler:public Sportist{
    private:
        int broj_na_odigrani_natprevari;
        int danocna_stapka;
    public:
        Fudbaler(string ime, int godina, int zarabotuvacka, int b, int d)
            :Sportist(ime, godina, zarabotuvacka)
        {
            broj_na_odigrani_natprevari = b;
            danocna_stapka = d;
        }
        float danok(){
            return getGodisnaZarabotuvackaEUR() * danocna_stapka;
        }
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, Fudbaler F){
            return os << "Ime: " << getIme() << endl
                      << "Godina na raganje: " << getGodinaNaRagjanje() << endl
                      << "Godisna zarabotuvacka(EUR): " << getGodisnaZarabotuvackaEUR() << endl
                      << "Danok sto treba da plati: " << danok();
        }
};
```

And I get 4 errors as described in title in these lines:

```
        return os << "Ime: " << getIme() << endl
                  << "Godina na raganje: " << getGodinaNaRagjanje() << endl
                  << "Godisna zarabotuvacka(EUR): " << getGodisnaZarabotuvackaEUR() << endl
                  << "Danok sto treba da plati: " << danok();
```

cannot call member function 'std::string Sportist::getIme()' without object

cannot call member function 'int Sportist::getGodinaNaRagjanje()' without object

cannot call member function 'int Sportist::getGodisnaZarabotuvackaEUR()' without object

cannot call member function 'float Fudbaler::danok()' without object

Comment: I dont understand why your operator overload is a friend function?

Comment: @Cool_Coder Because it's supposed to be? That's what my professor explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would say the function should be changed to

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, Fudbaler F){
            return os << "Ime: " << F.getIme() << endl
                      << "Godina na raganje: " << F.getGodinaNaRagjanje() << endl
                      << "Godisna zarabotuvacka(EUR): " << F.getGodisnaZarabotuvackaEUR() << endl
                      << "Danok sto treba da plati: " << F.danok();
        }
```

I am not shure about operator overloading for the `std::streams`. i usually have done that outside of the class. From your error messages, you need to use the passed `Fudbaler` variable to access the methods of it.